# cannot instantiate a class even though it is in a module

Tags: python

I want to use [`pycvss`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycvss/1.0.2) so I installed it via `pip`.

Instantiating the `Cvss()` class fails, though:

```
>>> import pycvss
>>> c = pycvss.Cvss()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cvss'
```

When inspecting the module it indeed looks quite empty:

```
>>> dir(pycvss)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

But when I check where python looks for the module:

```
>>> print(pycvss.__file__)
/usr/local/python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycvss/__init__.pyc
```

it looks like that,

`/usr/local/python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycvss/pycvss.py`

does define `Cvss():

```
(...)
class Cvss(object):
  """Common Vulnerability Scoring System.

  Use this class to set base, temporal and environmental vectors and
  compute scores.
  Cf module level documentation for sample usage.
  """

  _BASE_VECTOR = (AV, AC, Au, C, I, A)
(...)
```

I must be missing something obvious, but the more I look, the less I see (other modules are fine, including those installed by `pip` like for instance `requests`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`__init__` file](https://github.com/attwad/pycvss/blob/master/pycvss/__init__.py) in that project is *empty*. You need to import the [nested `pycvss` module](https://github.com/attwad/pycvss/blob/master/pycvss/pycvss.py):

```
from pycvss import pycvss

c = pycvss.Cvss()
```

The documentation is rather unclear about this; I'd file a [documentation issue](https://github.com/attwad/pycvss/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue) with the project.

Personally, I'd add one line to the `__init__.py` file here:

```
from pycvss import Cvss
```

and update the documentation to illustrate how to import that class.

Note that the project expects the [`enum` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to be available. If you are not using Python 3.4 or newer, you'll have to install the [`enum34` backport package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) too.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will file the documentation issue and a bug report as the `import` you mention throw a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unique'`

Comment: @WoJ You seem to running this in Python 2.7.8, have you installed any backports related to Python 3's `enum` module? (For ex: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I installed `enum` and, as you suggested, `enum34`. The error is still there.

Comment: @WoJ: you have another module named `enum` that is masking the proper module. What does `import enum; print enum.__file__` show was imported? Rename or remove that module.

Comment: @WoJ Then you'll have to remove https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum, pycvss is using `enum34`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you! I removed `enum`and everything imports fine.

Answer (score 1):

pycvss is a package you need to import it as

```
import pycvss.pycvss
c = pycvss.pycvss.Cvss()
```

or do it:-

```
from pycvss import pycvss
c = pycvss.Cvss()
```